# Double check/help modeling relationships with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm working on modelling a relationship between users and jobs where each user is matched to a job based on matches in the `user` parameters and `job eligibility` parameters.

I have the users and jobs tables preloaded with parameters and eligibility requirements, respectively, using the Faker gem.

Does it make sense to structure the relationship as simply users and jobs (a many-to-many relationship) or should I be thinking of this as three models: users, jobs, and matches?

If the latter, which is what I am leaning towards (it seemed comparable to the physicians have many appointments and through appointments have many patients example from the Active Records Association documentation seen here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html), what I have so far is:

User

```
      has_many :matches
      has_many :jobs, through: :matches
```

Jobs

```
      has_many :matches
      has_many :users, through: :matches
```

Matches

```
      belong_to :users
      belong_to :jobs
```

Is that correct? Should foreign keys on the matches table be the user_id and job_id.

Once the relationship is set, are there resources you can point me to on setting up the matching filters for this/walk through a few of them data comparisons?

For example, residency city and state and age for users needs to match those outlined on the eligibility requirements to be a match. i.e. only people under 24 living in SF, LA, and SD will be matched to any openings in those cities but users from other cities in CA nor other states nor those over 24 yr. won't be matched.

Comment: Hey, your question is very broad and more of a design than a programming question, this is not a good fit for Stackoverflow, also it is kind of hard to follow what you want. Because you talk about matches, but wouldn't matches be just whatever matches currently given the current data you have.

Comment: Do you really need to persists matches? What date what you save on them?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @Roland. Regarding what I want, are there any resources you can think of on matching/comparing databases and approaching design so I can do some more general reading on this space? Would love to have a plan of attack/framework mapped out before getting so far in on a build and realizing it doesn't quite make sense/work. I think I need to persist matches so they can later be called for users to apply to but I'm not 100% sure. Thanks so much!

Comment: The data I anticipate saving to matches is whether the user applied to the job and if the user was selected for the job. It seems like that would be the most appropriate table for that information?

Comment: So sounds more like you want to persist actual applications, matches by themselves do't seem to make a lot of sense to save.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I actually started working through and I think it's coming along well.